# Prove $v$ is harmonic and $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} v(re^{i\theta}) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

Prove that if $v(z) = \mathrm{Im}[(\frac{1+z}{1-z})^2]$, then $v$ is harmonic on the unit disc and $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} v(re^{i\theta}) = 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Explain why this does not contradict the maximum principle.

Comment: $(\frac{1+z}{1-z})^2$ is analytic on the unit disc so $v$ must be harmonic on the unit disc. I have problem with the second part of the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z(t)=\frac{ti}{2+ti}\in D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, where $t>0$, then $$v(z(t))= \mathrm{Im}[(\frac{1+z}{1-z})^2]= \mathrm{Im}[(1+ti)^2]=2t\to \infty \quad (t\to \infty).$$
Therefore $v(z)$ is not continuous and not bounded on the closed disc $\{|z|\le 1\}$. Thus the fact that 
$ v $ is harmonic on the unit disc and $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} v(re^{i\theta}) = 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$
 does not contradict the maximum principle.

Ofcourse if $v(z)$ is harmonic in $D$, continous on the closed disc $\{|z|\le 1\}$ and $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} v(re^{i\theta}) = 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, then $v(z)=0$ by the maximum principle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is "$v(z)$ in not continuous" a typo? Can you explain why $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} v(re^{i\theta}) = 0$ for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$? That is the part I don't get.

Comment: For $\theta \in (0, 2\pi), v(re^{i\theta})=\mathrm{Im}[(\frac{1-r^2+2ir\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta +r^2})^2]=\frac{4r(1-r^2)\sin \theta}{(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)^2}\to 0 (t\to 1)$

Comment: For $\theta =0,$ $v(r)=\mathrm{Im}[(\frac{1+r}{1-r})^2]=0\to 0(r\to 1)$.